# Python3 tkinter: Deletion of row of widgets works on first iteration but not on subsequent iterations

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter

I have created a widget that consists of rows and columns using tkinter entry widgets.  I wish to place a '-' button next to each row which will simply delete that row.

My object is called `DisplayTable`, which is an instance of `tk.Frame` and it consists of rows of entries, each row of which contains a button with a `-` on it that should allow easy removal of that row.

I'll try to skip the more verbose portions of the code so that I can get to the point.  The `DisplayTable` object creates a list of rows, `self.rows` within `__init__`.  As rows are added this list will grow.  For instance, a table that has three rows and two columns would look like:

```
[
    [<tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Button object>],
    [<tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Button object>],
    [<tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Entry object>, <tkinter.Button object>]
]
```

The resulting graphic:
[image: Resulting graphic]

In `DisplayTable.add_row()`, I have this code snippet (removed a lot of extra code to get to the point):

```
def add_row(self):
    row = []
    for i in range(self.columns):
        cell = tk.Entry(self)
        cell.grid(row=offset, column=i)
        row.append(cell)        

    row_to_delete = len(self.rows)
    btn = tk.Button(self, image=self.minus, command=lambda: self.delete_row(row_to_delete))
    btn.grid(row=offset, column=self.columns)
    row.append(btn)

    self.rows.append(row)
```

The above code snippet works perfectly for adding rows to the end of the array.  It works properly for row deletion one time.

```
def delete_row(self, row_number):
    for widget in self.rows[row_number]:
        widget.destroy()
    self.rows.pop(row_number)

    # re-assign the delete row buttons
    for i, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        button = row[-1]
        button.configure(command=lambda: self.delete_row(i))
```

My intent in delete_row is to re-assign the delete buttons since the row index of `self.rows` just changed for each row.  After executing this function, the behavior that I get is that the last `row_number` is always deleted.  For instance, if there are 10 rows, the row with index `9` is always deleted.

Replacing the re-assignment of the delete buttons with a more direct reference doesn't appear to change the behavior:

```
def delete_row(self, row_number):
    for widget in self.rows[row_number]:
        widget.destroy()
    self.rows.pop(row_number)

    # re-assign the delete row buttons
    for i, row in enumerate(self.rows):
        self.rows[i][-1].configure(command=lambda: self.delete_row(i))
```

Using `print` commands, I have verified that the variable `i` is definitely different on each round and that the `button` object referenced is a different button each time around, so the `command` assigned should also be different.  Somehow, it appears that only the last time around the loop is sticking to all o the buttons rather than just the one it was intended for.

Comment: BTW, it's great that you reduced the code in your question to focus on the problem, but it would have been even better if you had posted a [mcve] that we can run. If you'd done that, I would've been able to post my answer in half the time. ;)

Comment: You are correct, I should have posted a complete runnable, especially since I was 90% there with what I did post.  As is, I learned the necessary skill with the lambda nuance and won't likely make the same mistake again.  Thank you, again, for all of your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i, row in enumerate(self.rows):
    button = row[-1]
    button.configure(command=lambda: self.delete_row(i))
```

When the button is clicked, you delete the row specified by the value of the variable `i` *at that moment in time*.  Since this loop will have long since completed before you can possibly click a button, `i` will always refer to the last row.  This is a common problem with lambdas in a loop, and the solution is to capture the values of all used variables in default parameters: `command=lambda i=i: self.delete_row(i))`

I think a better approach would be to pass your `row` variable to delete_row(), rather than an index - that way, nothing needs to change when a row is deleted.  You can iterate `for widget in row:` to get the widgets to delete, and get rid of the row itself via `self.rows.remove(row)`.

Comment: I modified the question for clarity.  The code snipped that you refer to at the top of your answer is intended to operate on the 'remaining' rows after the target row is deleted.

Comment: Exactly - it is changing all of the remaining rows to delete row ``i``, which will end up being the last row (because that's the value ``i`` is left with after the loop completes).

Comment: Look again, `i` is never used to delete a row.  Row deletion happens in `for widget in self.rows: ....` and `self.rows.pop(row_number)`

Comment: So what do you think ``self.delete_row(i)`` is, if not using ``i`` to delete a row?

Comment: I see now.  I mis-read your answer (and multiple comments).  This worked perfectly.  Thank you so much for the input!  I don't use lambdas enough to know the nuances, but the solution indicates that I need to do some reading.

Comment: "a better approach would be to pass your row variable to `delete_row`" Great minds think alike. :)

Answer (score 1):

jasonharper has explained the cause of your problem: variables in `lambda`s aren't "frozen" at the time of creation, they're dynamic.

For further info, please see [Why do my lambda functions or nested functions created in a loop all use the last loop value when called?](http://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/) in the SO Python Wiki.

Here's a way to avoid that problem. We can use a default argument in the callback function. Default values are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it's called (it doesn't matter whether the function is a `lambda` or a full `def` function).

Rather than storing the row index number, which requires the messy re-assignment after row deletion, we can use the row object itself as the argument to the `delete_row` method.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Grid(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.pack()

        self.rows = []
        self.numcols = 3
        self.numrows = 4
        for _ in range(self.numrows):
            self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        rownum = len(self.rows)
        row = []
        for i in range(self.numcols):
            cell = tk.Entry(self)
            cell.grid(row=rownum, column=i)
            row.append(cell)

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='-', command=lambda r=row: self.delete_row(r))
        btn.grid(row=rownum, column=self.numcols)
        row.append(btn)

        self.rows.append(row)

    def delete_row(self, row):
        for widget in row:
            widget.destroy()
        self.rows.remove(row)


root = tk.Tk()
gui = Grid(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I was attempting to write this in a way that was easy to manage from a high-level API as well.  For instance, if I wanted to delete row 0, then I would like to simply delete row 0 rather than having to pull an instance of the row, then supply it to the delete_row() function.  Thank you, again!  Upvoted!

Comment: @slightlynybbled No worries. As for deleting a row via its index number, with my code you can just do `self.delete_row(self.rows[rownum])`. And of course you can define a convenience method like `def delete_row_num(self, rownum): self.delete_row(self.rows[rownum])`